# What am I doing wrong with my setup of Traefik, Cloudflare and Truenas?

Tags: cloudflare, traefik-ingress

I currently use a Cloudflare tunnel through the cloudflared app.  I have the tunnel up and running.  Within the tunnel I have a few public hostnames setup.

[image]

In Truenas I'm using clusterissuer for certificate management.
https://truecharts.org/charts/enterprise/clusterissuer/how-to

[image]

Traefik is also installed and seems to be working fine.

Lastly if you try to browse to the subdomain movies.*mydomain* and check the logs in cloudflared it shows the following errors.  I'm just not sure what they mean exaclty.  What am I doing wonrg?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try going into each of your public hostnames under your CloudFlare tunnel, additional application settings, TLS, and turning on no TLS verify. This solved the issue for me.

[image: Example.]